# Index out of range but it seems impossible because It's the length divided by 4

Tags: python, statistics

I want to do some statistical measurements to a dataset that I got, so when I tried to calculate one of the quartiles this error raised

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-7c758ed2f81d> in <module>
     20 t = len(dadosemarray) - 1
     21 
---> 22 quartis[0] = dadosemarray[int(t/4)] + 0.75*(dadosemarray[int(t/4) + 1] - dadosemarray[int(t/4)])
     23 quartis[1] = median(dadosemarray)
     24 quartis[2] = dadosemarray[int((3*t)/4)] + 0.25*(dadosemarray[int((3*t)/4) + 1] - dadosemarray[int((3*t)/4)])

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Like the title explains, there can't be a way that the index is out of range because it is the length of the list divided by 4.
The whole code is below

```
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
import statistics
from scipy.stats import kurtosis, skew

dadosemarray = []
quartis = []
percentis = []

i = 0

with open ("dados.txt", "r") as dados:
        dadosemarray = dados.readlines()
        
while i < 79:
    dadosemarray[i] = dadosemarray[i].replace("\n", "")
    dadosemarray[i] = int(dadosemarray[i])
    i+=1

t = len(dadosemarray) - 1
    
quartis[0] = dadosemarray[int(t/4)] + 0.75*(dadosemarray[int(t/4) + 1] - dadosemarray[int(t/4)])
quartis[1] = median(dadosemarray)
quartis[2] = dadosemarray[int((3*t)/4)] + 0.25*(dadosemarray[int((3*t)/4) + 1] - dadosemarray[int((3*t)/4)])
percentis = statistics.quantiles(dadosemarray, n=100)

print("quartis: {}".format(quartis))
assimetria = (quartis[0] + quartis [2] - 2*quartis[1])/(quartis[0] - quartis[2])
curtose = (quartis[2] - quartis[0])/(2*(percentis[89] - percentis[9]))

sb.boxplot(x=dadosemarray)

def curtosefun(valor):
    if valor > 0.263:
        print("A curtose de valor {} é leptocúrtica".format(curtose))
    elif valor < 0.263:
        print("A curtose de valor {} é platicúrtica".format(curtose))
    else:
        print("A curtose de valor {} é mesocúrtica".format(curtose))
        
def assimetriafun(valor):
    if valor > 0:
        print("O coeficiente de simetria de valor {} representa uma distribuição assimétrica negativa (à direita)".format(assimetria))
    elif valor < 0:
        print("O coeficiente de simetria de valor {} representa uma distribuição assimétrica negativa (à esquerda)".format(assimetria))
    else:
        print("O coeficiente de simetria de valor {} é simétrica".format(assimetria))

curtosefun(curtose) 
assimetriafun(assimetria)
```

I am trying to avoid using libraries to calculate because this is for a university subject that I took, I'm considering to calculate the percentils too but I need to resolve this first.

Comment: The error is about `quartis[0]`.

Comment: `quartis` is empty, there's no `quartis[0]`, so you can't assgn to it.

Comment: Use `quartis.append()` to add new elements to a list.